# An unclear Mathematica result for Borel summation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, summation

Summation of [divergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series)
is  applied in dynamical systems, q-difference equations, and mathematical physics nowadays
(for example, see [that book](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0830.34045) for info),
this is not an old-fashioned topic.

Mathematica includes, in particular, [Borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation).
More exactly, the `Regularization->Borel` option of the `Sum` command is the implementation of the
Borel's integral summation method with analytic continuation in Mathematica.

Trying `Regularization->Borel` in version 13 on Windows 10, I face a problem with the result of

```
Sum[n!, {n, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"]
```

> `-Subfactorial[-1]`

```
N[-Subfactorial[-1]]
```

> `0.697175 + 1.15573 I`

But directly using the definition of `Regularization -> "Borel"` in the
"Details" section  of the documentation to `Regularization`, I obtain

```
Sum[n!*t^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

> `1/(1-t)`

in a neighborhood of the origin.

First, the function `f[t_]:=1/(1-t)` cannot be analytically continued
along the positive ray because of  its singularity at `t==1` (e.g. see
[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) and
[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) for info).

Second, leaving aside the analytical continuation, the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-t}} {1-t} \, dt$ diverges
ant its principal value

```
Integrate[1/(1 - t)*Exp[-t], {t, 0, Infinity},  PrincipalValue -> True] // N
```

> `0.697175`

This numerically coincides with the real part of the Mathematica result. It should be stressed that  Wiki and Encyclopedia of Mathematics and G. H. Hardy's "Divergent series" say nothing about using principal values of integrals in Borel summation.

The article [Borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) of Wiki presents an example
in the "An alternating factorial series" section
$$ \sum _{k=0}^\infty k!(-z)^k =\frac {e^{\frac 1 z}} z \Gamma \left(0,\frac 1 z\right ), $$

but Wiki clearly says that is valid only in the so-called Borel polygon $\Re z > 0$ and [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Borel_summation_method) seconds it. The Google search
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k!$ does not bring the Mathematica result for it to me.

How to explain and ground the Mathematica result?

Edit. A typo: $\Re z > 0$  instead of $\Re z > 1$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My explanation, but not a justification, of the Mathematica result is as follows.

```
Sum[n!*(-z)^n, {n, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"] /. z -> -1
```

> `-(Gamma[0, -1]/E)`

```
N[%]
```

> `0.697175 + 1.15573 I`

The substitution `z->-1` in the above is wrong because $-1$ does not belong to the Borel polygon as it is explained in Wiki and G. H. Hardy's "Divergent series". If we allow such values, then (as far as I understand it) such a modification of Borel summation does not possess usual properties of a regularization: regularity, linearity, and stability. The correct result should be the returned input (as in many similar cases, say `Sum[n!/(n + 1), {n, 0, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Borel"]`).